# How do i make the menu on the side show properly

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

im trying to center my middle text while also having a side menu for my site. Unfortunately whenever i try to move the text in a suitable position, the border of the side menu shrinks.
Im also using bootstrap for certain parts of my code (4.5 version as some features i need are not available in the 5.0 version)
Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Divide et Impera</title>
    <link href="../css/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../css/fonts.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-transparent">
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon" style="color: #fff !important"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
              <div class="navbar-nav">
                <a class="nav-link nav-color nav-active" href="#">Home</a>
                <a class="nav-link nav-color" href="#">Introducere DEI</a>
                <a class="nav-link nav-color" href="#">DEI Iterativ</a>
                <a class="nav-link nav-color" href="#">Probleme DEI</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </nav>
          <div class="row " style="position: absolute; top: 50%; transform:translateY(-50%);">
              <div class="col-sm-2 ">
                <ul class="list-group" >
                    <li class="list-group-flush list-item-custom">Enunt</li>
                    <li class="list-group-flush list-item-custom">Rezolvare + cod</li>
                    <li class="list-group-flush list-item-custom">Explicatie rezolvare</li>
                    <li class="list-group-flush list-item-custom">Complexitate</li>
                    <li class="list-group-flush list-item-custom">Demonstratie inductiva</li>
                    <li class="list-group-flush list-item-custom">Executie</li>
                  </ul>
              </div>
          </div>

          <div class="container ">
            <div class="col">
              <div class="row-sm col-custom" >
                    Sa se demonstreze daca un arbore binar este de tipul BST
              </div>
              <div class="row-sm col-custom"> 
                    Observatie: un BST are urmatoarele proprietati:
              </div>
              <div class="row-sm col-custom">
                    •   Orice subarbore din partea stanga al unui nod contine valori mai mici decat nodul “tata”
              </div>
              <div class="row-sm col-custom">
                    •   Orice subarbore din partea dreapta al unui nod contine valori mai mari decat nodul “tata”
              </div>
              <div class="row-sm col-custom">
                    •   Atat subarborele drept, cat si cel stang trebuie sa fie la randul lor BST
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

How can i fix the shrinking ?

Edit: i forgot to add the css, my bad :P

```
html {
    font-family: 'Proxima Nova';
    font-weight: 200;
    font-size: 10px;
    max-height: 100%;
    background-color: #00000f;
}

body {
    width: 100%;
    color: #fff;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    font-family: "Proxima Nova" !important;
    font-size: 10px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    background-color: #00000f !important;
}

.navbar-custom {
    position: relative;
}

.abs-center-x {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.bg-transparent {
    background-color: transparent !important;
}

.nav-color {
    color :#fff !important;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 5px;
}

.nav-color:hover {
    color: #77dff1 !important;
}

.nav-active {
    color: #77dff1 !important;
}

.display-custom {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #77dff1;
    font-size: 17.5rem !important;
    text-align: center;
}

.lead-custom {
    font-size: 2.4rem;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 710px;
    line-height: 35px;
    color: #eeede7 !important;
}

/*Continut centru*/

#central {
    font-family: 'Proxima Nova', sans-serif;
    user-select: none;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#intro-wrap {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    max-width: 710px;
    width: 100%;
}

#intro {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #77dff1 !important;
    font-size: 17.5rem;
    text-align: center;
}

.intro {
    font-size: 2.4rem;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 710px;
    line-height: 35px;
    color: #eeede7 !important;
}

#hr {
    position: absolute;
    top: 90%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

hr {
    border-color: #77dff1 !important;
    max-width: 90%;
}


.button-wrap {
    postion: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 2.5rem;
}

.button-custom {
    font-family: 'Proxima Nova';
    font-weight: 600;
    background-color: transparent;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 2px solid #77dff1;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.button-custom:hover {
    font-weight: 100;
    color: #00000f;
    background: #77dff1;
}

/* probleme DEI */

.list-item-custom {
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #77dff1;
    color: #77dff1;
    padding: 2rem 4rem;
    margin-bottom: 0.7rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.list-item-custom:hover {
    background-color: #77dff1;
    color: #fff;
}

.col-sm-6 {
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #77dff1;
    color: #77dff1;
    padding: 2rem 4rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.col-hover:hover {
    font-weight: 100;
    color: #fff;
    background: #77dff1;
}

.col-custom{
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.75rem;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you are positioning the side menu, it's taking only 237px width to the left side. After that when you declare **div class="col-sm-2"**, its taking **(237px/12*2 = 39.5px)** space because of grid layout. From that 39.5px you took **40px + 40px = 80px** for **left and right padding**. So clearly no space for you **li**. And as a result it's border shrinks.

Code below-

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Divide et Impera</title>
    <link href="../css/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../css/fonts.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style>
      html {
    font-family: 'Proxima Nova';
    font-weight: 200;
    font-size: 10px;
    max-height: 100%;
    background-color: #00000f;
}

body {
    width: 100%;
    color: #fff;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    font-family: "Proxima Nova" !important;
    font-size: 10px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    background-color: #00000f !important;
}

.navbar-custom {
    position: relative;
}

.abs-center-x {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.bg-transparent {
    background-color: transparent !important;
}

.nav-color {
    color :#fff !important;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 5px;
}

.nav-color:hover {
    color: #77dff1 !important;
}

.nav-active {
    color: #77dff1 !important;
}

.display-custom {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #77dff1;
    font-size: 17.5rem !important;
    text-align: center;
}

.lead-custom {
    font-size: 2.4rem;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 710px;
    line-height: 35px;
    color: #eeede7 !important;
}

/*Continut centru*/

#central {
    font-family: 'Proxima Nova', sans-serif;
    user-select: none;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#intro-wrap {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    max-width: 710px;
    width: 100%;
}

#intro {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #77dff1 !important;
    font-size: 17.5rem;
    text-align: center;
}

.intro {
    font-size: 2.4rem;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 710px;
    line-height: 35px;
    color: #eeede7 !important;
}

#hr {
    position: absolute;
    top: 90%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

hr {
    border-color: #77dff1 !important;
    max-width: 90%;
}


.button-wrap {
    postion: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 2.5rem;
}

.button-custom {
    font-family: 'Proxima Nova';
    font-weight: 600;
    background-color: transparent;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 2px solid #77dff1;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.button-custom:hover {
    font-weight: 100;
    color: #00000f;
    background: #77dff1;
}

/* probleme DEI */

.list-item-custom {
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #77dff1;
    color: #77dff1;
    padding: 2rem 4rem;
    margin-bottom: 0.7rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: auto;
}

.list-item-custom:hover {
    background-color: #77dff1;
    color: #fff;
}

.col-sm-6 {
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #77dff1;
    color: #77dff1;
    padding: 2rem 4rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.col-hover:hover {
    font-weight: 100;
    color: #fff;
    background: #77dff1;
}

.col-custom{
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.75rem;
    font-weight: bold;
}
    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-transparent">
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon" style="color: #fff !important"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
              <div class="navbar-nav">
                <a class="nav-link nav-color nav-active" href="#">Home</a>
                <a class="nav-link nav-color" href="#">Introducere DEI</a>
                <a class="nav-link nav-color" href="#">DEI Iterativ</a>
                <a class="nav-link nav-color" href="#">Probleme DEI</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </nav>
          <div class="row " style="position: absolute; top: 50%; transform:translateY(-50%);">
              <div class="col-sm-12">
                <ul class="list-group" >
                    <li class="list-group-flush list-item-custom">Enunt</li>
                    <li class="list-group-flush list-item-custom">Rezolvare + cod</li>
                    <li class="list-group-flush list-item-custom">Explicatie rezolvare</li>
                    <li class="list-group-flush list-item-custom">Complexitate</li>
                    <li class="list-group-flush list-item-custom">Demonstratie inductiva</li>
                    <li class="list-group-flush list-item-custom">Executie</li>
                  </ul>
              </div>
          </div>

          <div class="container ">
            <div class="col">
              <div class="row-sm col-custom" >
                    Sa se demonstreze daca un arbore binar este de tipul BST
              </div>
              <div class="row-sm col-custom"> 
                    Observatie: un BST are urmatoarele proprietati:
              </div>
              <div class="row-sm col-custom">
                    •   Orice subarbore din partea stanga al unui nod contine valori mai mici decat nodul “tata”
              </div>
              <div class="row-sm col-custom">
                    •   Orice subarbore din partea dreapta al unui nod contine valori mai mari decat nodul “tata”
              </div>
              <div class="row-sm col-custom">
                    •   Atat subarborele drept, cat si cel stang trebuie sa fie la randul lor BST
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```